# Where to store role when dealing with role based authority?

Tags: node.js, angular, security, roles

where to store role of current login user (admin, normal user) when dealing with role based security in angular 7 ?
If i store it in local/session storage, anyone will be able to edit these roles.

Comment: Get the role as `jwt-token` in login API response. You can store this token in `local-storage or session-storage`, decode that jwt token in your application, whenever you needs to use it.

Comment: but i am creating token on node side, how can i decrypt/verify it on angular side?

Comment: If the login is successful you've to generate token in `node.js` and you've to send it back in response. use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt to decode the token to get the role.